# Is it likely that Oracle will ever change the way Java computes hash codes for java.lang.String's?

Tags: java, string, hash

Is it likely that Oracle will ever change the way Java computes hash codes for java.lang.String's?

I'm making an optimization that relies on the way hash codes are computed for strings, as per the java docs

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()

Comment: If you're truly concerned about the algorithm changing in the future, why not just make the algorithm in question your own code? The docs provide the algorithm, just reimplement it if you need to absolutely be sure it works the way you expect it.

Comment: Yeah you have ignored the obvious solution, oracle will change your own code - hash it. And mind you, there are different JVMs out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaDocs specify the interface just as much as the methods themselves. You can rely on it staying this way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on how likely it is but you can copy the existing hashcode implementation into your own utility class, and use that to generate your hashcodes. Just an FYI that `Apache Harmony JDK` uses a different algorithm to compute the [Hashcode](http://docjar.org/docs/api/org/apache/harmony/misc/HashCode.html).

Answer (score 1):

ABSOLUTELY NOT!! The reason is that java 7 has switch statements on Strings. The way this is implemented is really like

```
switch (myString) {
      case "hello":
           ...........
}
```

becomes

```
switch (myString.hashCode()) {
     case 3225263456234: //the hashcode of "hello"
            ......
}
```

What this means is that the compile time hashCode (the jdk used to compile the code) must be the same as the runtime jre. Therefore, it has to work if you compile in java 7 and run in some Java 10 version, and thus the hashCode must remain the same.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the job of the JIT to do the hashing, as it's translating from IL to native?